# Metal casting simulation and the solidification analysis

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, metallurgy, casting, production-technology

## Casting process analysis

Mold filling affects the quality of a casting. The fluid flow phenomena are closely related to the casting quality and surface finish. The dimensional accuracy of a casting and die life is also influenced by the fluid flow in the mold cavity. The metal flow pattern affects the temperature distribution of the mold cavity, which in turn would affect the solidification process.

Modeling of the mold filling could be complex due to multiple physical phenomena which need to be considered such as free surface flow, turbulence, surface tension and combination of fluid flow with heat transfer. To take all the necessary parameters into account, the simulation tends to become complicated.

## Question

Is there any software to simulate the casting and solidification? My preference order is:

1. Open source.
2. Free.
3. Proprietary and commercial.

Comment: A google search, what have you found already? You should make that clear so people don't waste time duplicating with things you have already found and discarded.

Comment: In case you haven't looked much yet, OpenFVM is generally considered a fairly easy way to get started. When/if you decide to get more serious, you might consider OpenFOAM (or you might prefer to skip OpenFVM and just use OpenFOAM from the beginning).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks. It was a great help :)